# Button effect using CSS causing problems with click event

Tags: css

So, I'm trying to add a 3D effect to a button using CSS. I've given it a bottom border, and on hover/when it's clicked, I change the size of the border as well as pushing it down an equal amount using relative positioning.

This works, and looks nice, but if I click near the top edge of the button, the click event doesn't fire - probably because the button has moved out of the way of the pointer.

Is there another way of achieving this effect (with pure CSS, not additional markup) without interfering with the click events?

Example:

```js
var initialCount = 0;
window.incrementCounter = function () {
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 'Counter: ' + ++initialCount;
}
```

```css
#counter {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

button {
  background: #ccc;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #aaa;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

button:hover {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  top: 1px;
}

button:active {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="counter">Counter: 0</div>
<button id="button" onClick="window.incrementCounter()">Increment</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `click` event you're binding to is only triggered once a successful `mousedown` and `mouseup` event have occurred. When the `mouseup` event occurs, the target is no longer the button (since it's been moved).

The easiest workaround for you is to bind your `incrementCounter()` function to the `mousedown` event, rather than `click`, as follows:

```
<button id="button" onmousedown="window.incrementCounter()">Increment</button>
```

See the snippet below for a working demo:

```js
var initialCount = 0;
window.incrementCounter = function () {
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 'Counter: ' + ++initialCount;
}
```

```css
#counter {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

button {
  background: #ccc;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #aaa;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

button:hover {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  top: 1px;
}

button:active {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="counter">Counter: 0</div>
<button id="button" onmousedown="window.incrementCounter()">Increment</button>
```

Please be advised though, that using obtrusive event handlers is quite bad practice. You would be better to use listeners outside of the DOM (i.e. directly inside your JS).

Comment: The mouse down event solves my issue nicely, cheers! And yes, this was just for the sake of simplicity in my snippet - in the "real" application the event handlers are bound through JS.

Comment: No problem at all, I suspected it was possibly a test-case, but thought I'd mention it anyway! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution would be to use margin instead of relative positioning.

```js
var initialCount = 0;
window.incrementCounter = function () {
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 'Counter: ' + ++initialCount;
}
```

```css
#counter {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

button {
  background: #ccc;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #aaa;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

button:hover {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

button:active {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="counter">Counter: 0</div>
<button id="button" onmousedown="window.incrementCounter()">Increment</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can also use w3.css in css. w3.css is very easy styling framework. Use

```
<div class="w3-hover">  for hover effect.
```